# Color Map with Geoshow in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, contour

I am plotting a contour over the mercator(planar) world map in MATLAB.

And I am successful but when I use the

```
geoshow('landareas.shp','FaceColor', [0.5 1.0 0,5])
```

it eliminates the contour plot on the map.

My code is:

```
axesm('mercator','MapLatLimit',[-50 90],'MapLonLimit',[0 250])

frame on;

grid on;

plotm(lat,long,'k')

contourfm(x,y,z)
```

Is there anyway to apply the

```
geoshow('landareas.shp','Display',[0.5 1.0 0.5])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know what exactly you would like to achieve so if my answer will be in a wrong direction we can elaborate more.

I used this code to produce a map with `contourfm` and `'landareas'`:

```
load geoid;
figure(1) 
axesm ('mercator','MapLatLimit',[-50 90],'MapLonLimit',[0 250])
contourfm(geoid,geoidrefvec, 'LineStyle', 'none');
geoshow('landareas.shp', 'FaceColor', [0.5 1.0 0.3]);
```

[image]

Instead of `geoid` you can have your own map but pay attention on the number of grid points. As far as I know they have to be 180x360.

One note. You may consider to use `coast` in stead of `landareas` because `contourfm` produces all colour map and `'landareas'` has also colours. So if it suit you, you can put only coast lines instead:

```
load geoid;
figure(2)
axesm ('mercator','MapLatLimit',[-50 90],'MapLonLimit',[0 250])
contourfm(geoid,geoidrefvec, 'LineStyle', 'none');
load coast
plotm(lat, long,'black') % plot the coast on the map
```

[image: contourfm with coast]

Comment: MasterPJ -- Thanks so much.  I have been needing an answer for sometime.  I almost gave up.

Comment: Please help me with this query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39155845/attaching-customized-colormap-to-geoshow-in-matlab