# attaching customized colormap to geoshow in matlab

Tags: matlab, colors, geospatial, raster

I am trying to plot a world map in mollweide projection using geoshow command. However, I am not able to modify the colors in the plot based on cutomized colormap values. Most likely this is an issue with how axesm and geoshow commands are used together, Please help me on this. See the ref. code below:

```
G = rand(180,360);
G(1:90,:)=-1*G(1:90,:);
R = georasterref('RasterSize',size(G),...
    'Latlim',[-90 90], 'Lonlim', [-180 180],'ColumnsStartFrom','north');

% ref this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727526/matlab-plot-raster-map-with-custom-colormap/34740112#34740112
%setting up graphics parameters 
my_colormap = [254  204   92
               253  141   60
               240   59   32
               189    0   38]/255 ;

startval=min(min(G));
endval=max(max(G));
nElements =size(my_colormap,1); 
stepSize=(endval-startval)/(nElements-1);
breaks = startval:stepSize:endval;
labels = textscan(num2str(round((breaks*100))/100),'%s') ;
labels = labels{1};
[~,indices] = histc(G,breaks);

%actual graphics               
figure
hm=axesm ('mollweid', 'Frame', 'on', 'Grid', 'off');
geoshow(G,R);%geoshow(indices,R);

colormap(my_colormap);
set(gca,'color','none');
set(gca,'box','off','xtick',[],'xcolor','none')
set(gca,'box','off','ytick',[],'ycolor','none')
hc=colorbar('location','southoutside');
caxis([breaks(1) breaks(length(breaks))])%caxis([0 length(breaks)-1])
hcP = [.7 .28 .2 .02];
set(hc,'position',hcP);
h.YTickLabel = labels ;
```

Answer (score 0):

one of my colleague pointed me to the solution and am posting it here for other's reference: 
geoshow(G,R,'DisplayType','texturemap')